# Draw a custom shape on a gameobject unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

I'm still newbie in unity and I'm sorry if this is a very obvious question. Actually, I'm trying to build a game where a thin object (the white stick in the figure below) is trying to touch a sphere object (the orange one in the image below). The red, green, blue and yellow lines are the raycasts fired from the top of the stick in different directions.[image]

The main goal is to draw on the sphere a black shape illustrating the intersection points between the stick and the sphere. To better understand it, we see in the following image the scene from a top view perspective with how it should look like if the stick do the job properly.[image]

To this end, I used this code to draw the raycast hit point but it is not working because `rend.material.mainTexture` is always `null` and I'm not sure why!!

```
RaycastHit hit_down, hit_right, hit_forward,  hit_left;         
        if (Physics.Raycast(stick.transform.position, stick.transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.down), out hit_down))
       {             
                 Debug.DrawRay(stick.transform.position, stick.transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.down) * hit_down.distance, Color.yellow);              
               Debug.Log("Point of contact down: "  + hit_down.point + " on " + hit_down.collider.gameObject.tag);
               if (hit_down.collider.gameObject.tag == "sphere")             
               {
         Renderer rend = hit_down.transform.GetComponent<Renderer>();
                     MeshCollider meshCollider = hit_down.collider as MeshCollider;

             Debug.Log(rend.material.mainTexture);
                     if (rend == null || rend.sharedMaterial == null || meshCollider == null)
                            return;
                     Texture2D tex = rend.material.mainTexture as Texture2D;
                     Vector2 pixelUV = hit_down.textureCoord;
                     pixelUV.x *= tex.width;
                     pixelUV.y *= tex.height;
                     tex.SetPixel((int)pixelUV.x, (int)pixelUV.y, Color.black);
                     tex.Apply();             
               } 
     }
```

One last question, is it the proper way to achieve my goal? Is there any other more efficient way to accomplish this task?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might lie in the line `Renderer rend = hit_down.transform.GetComponent<Renderer>();`

Because `rend.material.mainTexture` returns `null`, it would seem that `rend` itself is actually `null`. This might be caused by the type of `Renderer` you're trying to get.

You might want to try `Renderer rend = hit_down.transform.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();` instead. Everything else should work as intended